# Not able to remove docker artifactory container

Tags: docker, artifactory

we are trying to get rid of an artifactory container.

Nothing helps, things tried so far:

docker rm -f artifactory
docker update --restart=no artifactory
reboot

container keeps starting up:

docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest   "/entrypoint-artifac…"   17 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp            artifactory

What options do we have?

We do not have a docker-compose yaml file

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you using docker desktop? I am wondering if you have a k8s artifactory deployment. That can explain this behavior.
Try these commands
`kubectl get deployments -A`
if you find one, you can delete using

`#kubectl -n namespace delete deployment deployment-name
kubectl -n artifactory delete deployment artifactory`

Comment: There is no kubectl installed (command not found)

Comment: how about helm? can you try <code>helm ls -A<code>

Comment: There is no helm installed. Also docker service ps artifactory says no swarm.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to remove the container by hand:

```
systemctl stop docker  
docker ps --no-trunc to get the full container ID  
cd /var/lib/docker/containers  
rm -r <full container ID>  
systemctl start docker
```

Thanks to you all for your help,

Bodo